# How can I get a byte that represents an unsigned int in Java?

Tags: java, scala, serial-port, arduino, unsigned-integer

I have integers from 0 to 255, and I need to pass them along to an OutputStream encoded as unsigned bytes. I've tried to convert using a mask like so, but if i=1, the other end of my stream (a serial device expecting uint8_t) thinks I've sent an unsigned integer = 6.

```
OutputStream out;
public void writeToStream(int i) throws Exception {
    out.write(((byte)(i & 0xff)));
}
```

I'm talking to an Arduino at `/dev/ttyUSB0` using Ubuntu if this makes things any more or less interesting.

Here's the Arduino code:

```
uint8_t nextByte() {
    while(1) {
    if(Serial.available() > 0) {
        uint8_t b =  Serial.read();
      return b;
     }
    }
}
```

I also have some Python code that works great with the Arduino code, and the Arduino happily receives the correct integer if I use this code in Python:

```
class writerThread(threading.Thread): 
    def __init__(self, threadID, name):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
    def run(self):
        while True:
            input = raw_input("[W}Give Me Input!")
            if (input == "exit"):
               exit("Goodbye");
            print ("[W]You input %s\n" % input.strip())
            fval = [ int(input.strip()) ]
            ser.write("".join([chr(x) for x in fval]))
```

I'd also eventually like to do this in Scala, but I'm falling back to Java to avoid the complexity while I solve this issue.

Comment: Btw: `(byte(i & 0xFF)` is same as `(byte)i` many IO functions take an int in any case so you can just do OutputStream.write(i) and it writes the lowest 8-bits. i.e. it doesn't matter if you want it to be a signed or unsigned value. i.e. you are making the issue too complicated because it all works out the same. ;)

Comment: It seems that DataOutputStream will be useful (as soon as you need to send something more complex than bytes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast, then mask: `((byte)(i)&0xff)`

But, something is very strange since:

(dec)8 - (binary)1000
(dec)6 - (binary)0110

[edit]
How is your Arduino receiving 6 (binary)0110 when you send 1 (binary)0001?
[/edit]

Comment: out.write(((byte)i) & 0xff); seems to do the same thing. The device on the other end still interprets (i=1) like I sent a 6.

Comment: you have bigger problems than casting in this case.

Comment: I'm updating the question to show the arduino code. I should add that it works great with the current Arduino code if I use python and pyserial.

Comment: Tried a different arduino and it worked. I think something is wrong with this one!

Comment: @Martin: If your problem is solved, please either add a self-answer and accept it, or edit your question with the solution.  So others don't spend their time working on an unneeded answer.

Comment: @SW Monkey - he did accept with an explanation in the accepted answer (right above your comment)

Comment: An edit to the question would be more visible. I've proposed an edit myself but have no edit privilege, so the edit is waiting to be published.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want `out.write(i)` here. Only the eight low-order bits are written from the int argument `i`.

Comment: It looks like you're correct that out.write(i) is equivalent. Unfortunately, I still don't get the right byte value, though. The serial device tells me it got a uint8_t = 6.

Comment: Do all other integers 0 to 255 work? If none do I suspect you're dealing with not the right byte somehow (headers or what not). If all the rest work then that's really odd.